# `apt-get install software-properties-common` is broken

Tags: apt, package-management

When running `apt-get install software-properties-common`, we get the following error message:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info-data/distro-info-data_0.38ubuntu0.2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

When navigating to "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info-data/", we see that particular version "distro-info-data_0.38ubuntu0.2_all.deb" is missing from the list. Please advise on what the next step is. Thanks!

Comment: please do a `sudo apt-get update` and try again!

Comment: Quite likely you don't need that command. What it installs is already there by default.